# Arrival time in Poisson Processes

Tags: probability, markov-chains, poisson-process

I'm trying to work out a question from my textbook - any small tips or hints would be greatly appreciated!

If tornadoes hit a region according to a Poisson process with $\lambda = 2$, and the number of insurance claims filed after any tornado follows a Poisson distribution with mean 30, then what is the expectation of the total number of claims filed by time t?

\begin{align}
\text{Since $N_t$ has a Poission distribution, then} \ E(N_t)=\lambda t
\end{align}
This means that we expect about 2t torando hits in time t. Since the file claims also follows a poisson distribution with mean 30,

\begin{align}
E(\text{number of claims})=\lambda*\text{number of hits in time t} 
\end{align}

Then, $E(\text{number of claims})=60t$.

Is my reasoning wrong? I'm not really sure how to approach this problem! Thanks a ton in advance

Comment: Your use of $E[\mbox{num claims}] = \lambda (\mbox{ num hits in time $t$})$ does not make sense because the left-hand-side is an expectation while the right-hand-side is a random variable.  For this problem you need to use iterated expectations.  Let $M_i$ be the number of claims filed after tornado $i$, let $M$ be the total claims up to time $t$, then you have $M =\sum_{i=1}^{N_t} M_i$ (and you can condition on $N_t$, that is, $E[M] = E[E[M|N_t]]$).  Doing this you will formally get the answer your intuited. (Assuming $M_i$ is independent of $N_t$)

Comment: @Michael thank you for your answer - I considered your explanation but I was not able to approach the problem with that way. Instead I thought of a more "intuitive" way of doing the question. Using the notations that you have used, we know that $M_i \sim Po(30)$. Since this is a poisson process, we know that the number of tornado hits will be (on average) $\lambda t$ at time t. Then $M=\sum_{i=0}^{\lambda t} M_i$. Since the sum of poisson RVs are poisson again, we can find the expectation of M quite easily from this. Is my intuition correct or am I forgetting something again?

Comment: The value $\lambda t$ is not necessarily an integer, and so it does not make sense to sum $\sum_{i=0}^{\lambda t}$.  If you prefer, you can compute $E[M]$ using the "law of total expectation," which is essentially equivalent to iterated expectations in this case but may simplify notation: We have $M = \sum_{i=1}^{N_t} M_i$.  Then $$ E[M] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} E[M|N_t=n]P[N_t=n]$$ So the next step is to compute $E[M | N_t=n]$ using the definition of $M$, ...